# Replacing two matched values with NA

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two variables that are scored on a scale from 1-6. I want to identify cases where individuals answered 3 on variable 1 and a 3 on variable 2 and change those to NA.

```
help <- data.frame(id   = c(100, 100, 100, 110, 110, 110, 120, 120, 120, 130, 130, 130),
                   var1 = c(1, 3, 6, 3, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6),
                   var2 = c(5, 3, 6, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6, 6, 3, 5, 4))
```

I am hoping for an end result that looks like this:

```
    id var1 var2
   100    1    5
   100    NA   NA
   100    6    6
   110    NA   NA
   110    4    4
   110    NA    NA
   120    1    5
   120    2    6
   120    3    6
   130    NA   NA
   130    5    5
   130    6    4
```

I have experimented with data.table and the match() command, to no avail. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: *I have experimented with data.table and the match() command, to no avail* : `library(data.table) ; setDT(help)[(var1 == var2) & (var1 == 3L), c("var1", "var2") := NA_integer_]`

Comment: Simple assignment in base R: `help[help$var1 == 3 & help$var2 == 3, c("var1","var2")] <- NA`

Answer (score 5):

You can do a simple subset and assignment in base R with:

```
help[help$var1 == 3 & help$var2 == 3, c("var1","var2")] <- NA

help
#    id var1 var2
#1  100    1    5
#2  100   NA   NA
#3  100    6    6
#4  110   NA   NA
#5  110    4    4
#6  110   NA   NA
#7  120    1    5
#8  120    2    6
#9  120    3    6
#10 130   NA   NA
#11 130    5    5
#12 130    6    4
```

If you have `NA`s you can do a similar logic, just need to replace the `NA`s for subsetting:

```
ind <- help$var1 == 3 & help$var2 == 3
help[replace(ind, is.na(ind), FALSE), c("var1","var2")] <- NA
```

Comment: I had that but didn't include the `c("var1","var2")` piece... Thank you.

Comment: Quick follow-up... If there are any missing values in those variables I get the following error _Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, help$var1 == 3 & help$var2 == 3, c("var1",  : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames_ ... Any ideas how to move around this?

Comment: yes that is perfect. can you explain the steps here? it looks like `ind` is a list of TRUE/FALSE and NA values, then you run that through the replace command and replace only TRUE instances with NA. Is that correct?

Comment: @bpace, yup that is what I do. I replace all the instances where `ind` is `NA` with `FALSE` so that it can be used in the subset. Unfortunately, I don't think there is any operator similar to `==` but that returns on `TRUE` or `FALSE` which is why I use the `replace`

Comment: @MikeH. Re your last comment, there's `c(NA, 1, 2) %in% 2` though it won't always be a good substitute. David's data.table approach will also work without adjustment for the NA case, I guess, since `DT[logi, j]` filters out NAs in logi.

Comment: @Frank, thanks didnt think about `%in%`! I wonder if `%in%` is faster than `==` + `replace`...

Comment: Very preliminary timing shows `%in%` is a bit slower: `x <- sample(c(NA,1:100), 1e6, replace = TRUE);
eq_replace <- function(x){ind <- x ==3;replace(ind, is.na(ind), FALSE)};
in_op <- function(x){x %in% 3};
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(in_op(x), eq_replace(x), times = 20L)
`

Comment: Ok, interesting. I just meant that it exists and has the TRUE/FALSE only behavior, not that it's better in terms of performance or generalizability or anything. Really, one might want the error on NA from == if NAs are not expected.

Comment: Yup, sorry the benchmarking was really just for my own curiosity!